# PHP cleanup "&$"

Tags: php, html, unicode

I'm trying to convert HTML to plain text. I get many `&\#8217;` `&\#8220;` etc.

I have tried:

1. `html2text` command line
2. `html_entity_decode` + `ENT_QUOTES` | `ENT_HTML401` `UTF-8`
3. `html_entity_decode(htmlentities($str))`
4. `strip_tags`
5. `trim`

It did help a lot for cleaning up other things, but those `&\#8217;` `&#8220;` don't get fixed. How can I convert them correctly?

Comment: Do you mean `&#8217;` and `&#8220;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried "htmlspecialchars_decode"

```
<?php
$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
<p>this -> "</p>
<p>this -> &quot;</p>
```